# net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 does not work

Tags: linux, tcp

I set the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries2 = 15`, but it doesn't work.
I found it just 8 retransmisson packages. Why?

Thanks.

[wireshark ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTDah.png)

Comment: How long did you capture for?

Comment: about 10 minutes, and all of these 8 packages are captured in the first minute.

Comment: 15 retries should take between 15 and 30 minutes.   Wait it out and see.

Comment: But the 9th package did not appear in last 9 minutes, is it a normal phenomenon?

Comment: TCP doesn't specify the exact timing by which retransmits happen.   (Measuring this and comparing with known implementations is actually one of the ways you can "fingerprint" a box on the network and guess what OS it is running!)

Comment: Thank you, I will try again.